# TypeError: partitions must be TopicPartition namedtuples

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I want to use `KafkaConsumer` from `kafka-python` to consumer the first N messages in a topic:

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer as kc
import json

bootstrap_servers = ['xx.xxx.xx.xxx:9092']
topic_name = 'my_topic_name'

consumer = kc(topic_name, group_id='group1', bootstrap_servers=bootstrap_servers,
              auto_offset_reset='earliest', auto_commit_interval_ms=1000,
              enable_auto_commit=True,
              value_deserializer=lambda x: json.loads(x.decode('utf-8')))
count = 0
consumer.seek_to_beginning((topic_name,0))
kjson = []
for msg in consumer:
    if count < 10:
        count = count + 1
        kjson.append(msg.value)
    else:
        print(json.dumps(kjson, indent=4))
        break
```

This line `consumer.seek_to_beginning((topic_name,0))` gives me the above error. The [documentation](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaConsumer.html) specifies:

```
seek_to_beginning(*partitions)[source]
Seek to the oldest available offset for partitions.

Parameters: *partitions – Optionally provide specific TopicPartitions, otherwise default to all assigned partitions.
Raises: AssertionError – If any partition is not currently assigned, or if no partitions are assigned.
```

There are 32 partitions in this topic (indexed from `0` to `31`). What would be the right syntax to start from the very beginning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says

> must be TopicPartition namedtuples

e.g.

```
from kafka.structs import TopicPartition


...
consumer.seek_to_beginning(TopicPartition(topic_name,0))
```

> There are 32 partitions in this topic (indexed from 0 to 31)

```
tps = [TopicPartition(topic_name, i) for i in range(32)]
consumer.seek_to_beginning(tps)
```

Comment: Thanks. I need to remove the ```topic_name``` argument in the line ```consumer = kc....``` for this syntax. It works.